# PHP GD 2 Colour 3 step Gradient?

Tags: php, png, gd, gradient, linear-gradients

I am trying to take a png image (which has a transparent background and black is the only foreground colour) and overlay a 2 colour 3 step linear gradient only on the black foreground.

Example; from bottom to top: 0% - colour 1, 50% colour 2, 100% colour 1.

Is this possible to have the gradient only affect the black foreground in php-gd? If so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: gd imagecopyresampled with appropriate options to preserve transparency? gd won't build the gradient for you, though.

Comment: I can do the transparency just fine...the original image has a white background and using: function maketransparent($oldfile,$newfile){
  $im = imagecreatefrompng($oldfile);
  $img = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
  $trans = imagecolorallocate($img, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
  imagecolortransparent($img,$trans);
  imagecopy($img,$im,0,0,0,0,200,200);
  imagetruecolortopalette($img, true, 256);
  imageinterlace($img);
  imagepng($img,$newfile);
  //imagedestroy($img);
 } I can make the white part of the image transparent, just need to figure our gradients